# Block spam emails in cake php website - mandrill

Tags: cakephp, captcha, mandrill, spam-prevention, email-spam

I have this listing site built up in cake php. The site has profile pages containing contact forms to contact these profile owners. I have integrated mandrill to this site to manage email notification sendings. 
If a general visitor contact the profile owner then email goes to three people

1. To the Profile owner
2. To the site Admin
3. To visitor as well.

Now the problem is certain domains are continuously trying to send spam messages to my clients. 
I have tried following to block these emails:

1. From Mandrill Settings, I have blocked these emails. This method works 
    perfectly in blocking all 3 emails initiated by spammer's email but then I
   cannot block such emails all the time, as this doesn't block whole domain.
2. In mandrill Outbound, I have set up Rules to block emails which contain spammy content. But then I can only prevent email sending from my site to these emails and NOT what these email addresses send to my clients. As this only work for outbound emails and not inbound emails.

I have also added math captcha tool (as mandatory obviously) in the forms.

The site is hosted on Linux server. is there any way to prevent these spam emails by setting some rules like

> if the email address or body contains words like 'seo, promotion..' 
>   then Reject email

So it will block all such emails:
seo@example.com
abc@seo.com
a.bc@hostsite.com

Thank you for reading and sorry if I am confusing you.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are still experiencing spam issues after adding a captcha, then I would say your captcha is not working (properly). Google's Recaptcha always works very well for me: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/

Comment: @FrankSunnyman I have tried filling wrong value in captcha then it doesn't let me submit the form. Hence captcha is working fine.

Comment: Then the spambots probably know how to answer your captcha

Comment: Match captha is very weak and does not provide appropriate protection for automatic form submission. And script can read that and "do the math"